# Connect RHPAM with External Oracle DB so that I can login with Username and password define in External Database

Tags: jbpm, rhpam

I am getting below error while starting my RHPAM server. Business central is UP but I am not able to ,login into that.
[org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
18:59:07,309 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/default-kieserver error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/default-kieserver response code 405

I have made changes in standalone-full.xml file for datasource and also created two tables in my database. I am attaching standalone-full.xml file.

Table structure:
CREATE TABLE Users(user_name VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY, passwd VARCHAR(64), user_email VARCHAR(100), user_lang VARCHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE UserRoles(user_name VARCHAR(64), userRoles VARCHAR(64)).

Changes in Standalone-full.xml file:
I have deleted some of the lines below so that text can be accomodated here.

```
    
    <system-properties>
        <property name="org.kie.example" value="true"/>
        <property name="org.jbpm.designer.perspective" value="full"/>
        <property name="designerdataobjects" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.user" value="admin"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.pwd" value="Vihaan@123"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.location" value="http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.id" value="default-kieserver"/>
        <property name="org.drools.server.ext.disabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.jbpm.server.ext.disabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.jbpm.ui.server.ext.disabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.optaplanner.server.ext.disabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.jbpm.case.server.ext.disabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.kie.dmn.server.ext.disabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.kie.swagger.server.ext.disabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="org.kie.prometheus.server.ext.disabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.controller" value="http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.controller.user" value="admin"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.controller.pwd" value="Vihaan@123"/>
        <property name="org.kie.server.bypass.auth.user" value="true"/>
        <property name="org.jbpm.ht.callback" value="db"/>
    </system-properties>
    <!--<vault>
        <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="${jboss.home.dir}/vault.keystore"/>
        <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" value="MASK-0Iom9.IBeQ54rb9KfOaGo9"/>
        <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_ALIAS" value="vault"/>
        <vault-option name="SALT" value="dpIHkkuW"/>
        <vault-option name="ITERATION_COUNT" value="50"/>
        <vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="${jboss.home.dir}/vault"/>
    </vault>-->
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:2.0">
            <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
            <default-thread-pool name="batch"/>
            <job-repository name="in-memory">
                <in-memory/>
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool name="batch">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:core-management:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
            <datasources>
                <!--<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>-->
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ISTDB" pool-name="ISTDB">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.55.81:1521:p1usutf</connection-url>
                    <driver>Oracle</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>ods_appn</user-name>
                        <password>ods_appn</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="Oracle" module="com.oracle.database.jdbc">
                        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:discovery:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:distributable-web:2.0" default-session-management="default" default-single-sign-on-management="default">
            <infinispan-session-management name="default" cache-container="web" granularity="SESSION">
                <primary-owner-affinity/>
            </infinispan-session-management>
            <infinispan-single-sign-on-management name="default" cache-container="web" cache="sso"/>
            <infinispan-routing cache-container="web" cache="routing"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
            <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ISTDB" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee-security:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:6.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple"/>
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default">
                <channel-creation-options>
                    <option name="MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="1234" type="remoting"/>
                </channel-creation-options>
            </remote>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="60" unit="seconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
            <statistics enabled="${wildfly.ejb3.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
            <log-system-exceptions value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:8.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
            <providers>
                <aggregate-providers name="combined-providers">
                    <providers name="elytron"/>
                    <providers name="openssl"/>
                </aggregate-providers>
                <provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
                <provider-loader name="openssl" module="org.wildfly.openssl"/>
            </providers>
            <audit-logging>
                <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
            </audit-logging>
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
            <security-realms>
                <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
                <properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                    <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
                <properties-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                    <users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
            </security-realms>
            <mappers>
                <simple-permission-mapper name="default-permission-mapper" mapping-mode="first">
                    <permission-mapping>
                        <principal name="anonymous"/>
                        <permission-set name="default-permissions"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                    <permission-mapping match-all="true">
                        <permission-set name="login-permission"/>
                        <permission-set name="default-permissions"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                </simple-permission-mapper>
                <constant-realm-mapper name="local" realm-name="local"/>
                <simple-role-decoder name="groups-to-roles" attribute="groups"/>
                <constant-role-mapper name="super-user-mapper">
                    <role name="SuperUser"/>
                </constant-role-mapper>
            </mappers>
            <permission-sets>
                <permission-set name="login-permission">
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.security.auth.permission.LoginPermission"/>
                </permission-set>
                <permission-set name="default-permissions">
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/>
                </permission-set>
            </permission-sets>
            
            
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:iiop-openjdk:2.1">
            <orb socket-binding="iiop" ssl-socket-binding="iiop-ssl"/>
            <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/>
            <security server-requires-ssl="false" client-requires-ssl="false"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:9.0">
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="sso">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="routing"/>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
                <local-cache name="default">
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <object-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <object-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:3.0">
            <worker name="default"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:5.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:3.0">
            <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:8.0">
            <server name="default">
                <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                    <role name="admin" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-acceptor>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-config-smallrye:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-health-smallrye:2.0" security-enabled="false" empty-liveness-checks-status="${env.MP_HEALTH_EMPTY_LIVENESS_CHECKS_STATUS:UP}" empty-readiness-checks-status="${env.MP_HEALTH_EMPTY_READINESS_CHECKS_STATUS:UP}"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-metrics-smallrye:2.0" security-enabled="false" exposed-subsystems="*" prefix="${wildfly.metrics.prefix:jboss}"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-opentracing-smallrye:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0">
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:request-controller:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/ISTDB"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd from Users username where user_name=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select userRoles, 'Roles' from UserRoles where user_name=?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

I should be able to login with user defined in my database.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.